# Is loading additional CSS in the HEAD, according to screen size, a bad practice?

Tags: css, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I'm using the tablesaw script to fit tables to smaller screens.

My developer inserted the relevant CSS inside the `head` tag, this way:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/tablesaw.css" media="screen and (max-width: 767px)">`

The problem is that it is hurting my Google Page-Speed Score for mobile devices, since this is a render blocking element, that comes in addition to my general CSS file.

Therefore, I figure I can just take [the whole Tablesaw CSS block](https://github.com/filamentgroup/tablesaw/blob/master/dist/tablesaw.css), and insert it inside the general CSS file, right at the end of it, But I will need to wrap it like this:

`@media screen and (max-width: 767px){[General TableSaw Content][by @media-type Table Saw Content]}`

And this indeed increased my page speed score.

So is this a better practice?

Any disadvantages over the method I'm currently using (loading the additional CSS in the `head` section)?

Comment: This is normal. If your score there in the green zone - your developer has done it right. Just green zone (>=85), it doesn't need to be 100/100. There are alternatives like above-fold critical styles inserted right into the page and the rest of styles is loaded in async mode via javascript, not loaded via link tag, but this is some kind of super optimization your site might not need. Usually there are bunch of other stuff to improve before this issue with css can be taken into the consideration.

Comment: Well, In mobile, If I do both this, and use Google Web Font Loader, I go from 79 to 88 (yellow to green), and on desktop, from 91 to 95.

Comment: well, I missed that this is your additional file. If it is not big (which I guess is the case) just add those additional styles to your main stylesheet.